# Parse any character until semicolon in ANTLR4

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I am trying to parse the following grammar, where `Value` can be any character up to the semicolon, but I cannot get it to work correctly:

```
grammar Test;

pragmaDirective : 'pragma' Identifier Value ';' ;

Identifier : [a-z]+ ;

Value : ~';'* ;

WS : [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip ;
```

When I test it with `pragma foo bar;`, I get the following error:

```
line 1:6 extraneous input ' ' expecting Identifier
line 1:11 extraneous input 'bar' expecting ';'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pragmaDirective : 'pragma' Identifier .*? ';' ;
```

and remove the `Value` rule. That should do the job.

And a recommendation: define **lexer** rules for your literals (like 'pragma') instead of defining them directly in the parser rules.

Comment: I ended up defining a new parser rule for the pragma value. This was my first attempt at writing a parser with ANTLR and I should have done some further reading. Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

The Value rule is much too greedy. Lexer rules try to match as much as possible, so for input like this: `pragma mu foo;`, the Value rule would match `pragma mu foo`. After all, that's zero or more characters other than a semicolon.

`Value` is not well suited to be used as a lexer rule. I suggest you rethink your approach. Perhaps create a parser rule `value` that matches an `Identifier` and perhaps other lexer rules. Hard to make a suggestion without seeing much of the "real" grammar (you probably posted a dumbed down version of the grammar you're working on).